# I've downloaded a file via git clone to my notebook on google colab, how do I determine that file's path now?

Tags: filepath, google-colaboratory

To be clear this file was NOT imported from Google Drive, instead it was downloaded directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%pwd` to show the current directory, `%cd` to switch directories, and `!ls` to list directories. (Or, use the file browser GUI on the left hand side.)

Here's an example:
[image]